# javascript (post in post)

Tags: javascript, asp.net

My code :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function () {
                  $.post("/Game/GetPlayers", function (data) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.player.length; i++) {
                        if ("@Session.SessionID" == data.player[i].AgainstId);
                        {
                           //some code
                        }
                        $("<li></li>").text(data.player[i].Name).on("click", function () {
\*when i click - field hide */            $(this).hide();
                      $.post("/Game/SetId", { name: data.player[i].Name },function(data2) {
                                alert(data2);
                            });
                        }).prependTo("ol");
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
```

Why tag(li) disappear when i click but second post request doesn'n work? Is it possible (request in request)?

Comment: there is a `;` at the end of `if` statement, remove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `li` click is causing a error `data.player[i] is undefined`.

It is because of the usage of closure variable `i`. Then the click event happens `i` will have the value `data.player.length` but `data.player[data.player.length]` is undefined.

```
$(function() {
    $.post("/Game/GetPlayers", function(data) {
        $.each(data.player, function(i, v) {
            if ("@Session.SessionID" == v.AgainstId) {
                // some code
            }
            $("<li></li>").text(v.Name).on("click", function() {
                // when i click - field hide
                // $(this).hide();
                $.post("/Game/SetId", {
                            name : v.Name
                        }, function(data2) {
                            alert(data2);
                        });
            }).prependTo("ol");
        });
    });
})
```

Another option is to use event delegation

```
$(function() {
    $.post("/Game/GetPlayers", function(data) {
        $.each(data.player, function(i, v) {
            if ("@Session.SessionID" == v.AgainstId) {
                // some code
            }
            $("<li></li>").text(v.Name).data("player",
                    v.name).prependTo("ol");
        });
    });

    $('ol').on('click', 'li', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        // when i click - field hide
        // $(this).hide();
        $.post("/Game/SetId", {
            name : $this.data('player')
        }, function(data2) {
            alert(data2);
        });
    });
});
```